# @api_view method not works but post method works django rest api

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have imported `django_restframework.decorators from api_view`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_cart(self,request):
    serializer = CartItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart-items/ -d "{\"product_name\":\"name\",\"product_price\":\"41\",\"product_quantity\":\"1\"}"
```

When I use `@api_view(['GET'])` I get this error

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

But When I change like this it works

```
def post(self,request):
    serializer = CartItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart-items/ -d "{\"product_name\":\"name\",\"product_price\":\"41\",\"product_quantity\":\"1\"}"
```

It returns success 200

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "product_name": "item",
        "product_price": 12.5,
        "product_quantity": 5
    }
}
```

CartItemView code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import CartItemSerializer
from .models import CartItem
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class CartItemViews(APIView):
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def post_cart(self,request):
        serializer = CartItemSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    def get(self,request, id=None):
        if id:
            item = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = CartItemSerializer(item)
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        items = CartItem.objects.all()
        serializer = CartItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def patch(self,request, id=None):
        if id:
            item = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = CartItemSerializer(item,data=request.data,partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
               serializer.save()
               return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data})
            else:
               return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors})

    def delete(self, request, id=None):
        item = get_object_or_404(CartItem, id=id)
        item.delete()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": "Item Deleted"})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CartItemViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('cart-items/',CartItemViews.as_view()),
    path('cart-items/<int:id>', CartItemViews.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: HOw do you *register* the view?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `@api_view(['POST'])` on the member of a class-based view: the [**`@ap_view(…)`** decorator <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) turns a function into a *class-based view*, so now your `post_cart` is a class inside a class.

What you can use to route a POST request to a method that is not named `post` is [**`@action(…)`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action


class CartItemViews(APIView):
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def post_cart(self, request):
        # …
        pass
```

That being said, I don't see why using `def post` would not work here.

Comment: AssertionError: @action() missing required argument: 'detail'
I got this error and added @action(methods=['post'],detail=True)

but still it throws POST method not allowed

Comment: @Balaji: `detail=False`

Comment: still the error occurs 
`[14/Mar/2024 21:03:37] "POST /api/cart-items/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41`

Comment: sorry I am new to django

Answer (score 0):

1. Original Issue:

> When I use @api_view(['GET']) I get this error: "detail": "Method
> "POST" not allowed."

When You change it to `@api_view(['POST'])` you are only allowing Post requests. If you want both Get and Post requests you should set it to
`@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])`

2. The issue when you used class-based View:

> still the error occurs [14/Mar/2024 21:03:37] "POST /api/cart-items/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41

You should make a post request to `/api/cart/post_cart/` or set  `url_path='cart-items' and url_name='cart-items'` on `@action` decorator. [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions)

> By default, the URL pattern is based on the method name, and the URL name is the combination of the ViewSet.basename and the hyphenated method name.